# How to connect a checkbox in my HTML with my model User?

Tags: python, django

When user is being registered I want him to check a checkbox if he is from an access challenge area. If user checks 'access challenge area' checkbox I want to show only his email address and hide his city name and address.

I added a field access_challenge = BooleanField(default = False) in my User model.

I created a checkbox in my registration html template.

And in my other html where the list of the posts I did:

```
{% if user.access_challenge %}

<p> {{ post.email }} </p>

{% else %}

<p> {{ post.country }} </p>
<p> {{ post.city }} </p>
<p> {{ post.address }} </p>
<p> {{ post.email }} </p>
```

my models.py

```
from PIL import Image
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="First name", max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="First name", max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(verbose_name="Country name", max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name="City name", max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email", max_length=255)
    access_challenge = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:blog')


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView, DetailView, ListView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .forms import UserCreationModelForm
from .models import User, Post

class UserRegistrationView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'users/registration.html'

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'country', 'city', 'address', 'email', 'phone', 'website']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'country', 'city', 'address', 'email', 'phone', 'website']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

class CabinetView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

def blog(request):

    context = {
            'posts': Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    }
    return render(request, 'users/post_list.html', context)


def countries(request):

    user = User.objects.all().distinct('access_challenge')
    country = Post.objects.all().distinct('country')

    context = {
            'posts': country,
            'user': user
    }

    return render(request, 'users/countries.html', context)



def cities(request, pk):

    country = Post.objects.get(id=pk).country
    cities = Post.objects.filter(country=country).distinct('city')

    context = {
        'cities':cities,
        'country':country
    }

    return render(request, 'users/cities.html', context)

def address(request, pk):

    city = Post.objects.get(id=pk).city
    address = Post.objects.filter(city=city)

    context = {
        'address': address,
        'city': city

    }

    return render(request, 'users/address.html', context)

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/home.html')
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Profile

User = get_user_model()

class UserCreationModelForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'country', 'city', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'access_challenge']


class UserUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserRegistrationView, CabinetView, PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDetailView, PostDeleteView
from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/register/', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/', CabinetView.as_view(), name='cabinet'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/countries/', views.countries, name='countries'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/cities/<int:pk>/', views.cities, name='cities'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/address/<int:pk>/', views.address, name='address'),


]
```

my registration.html

```
{% extends 'shared/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content-section mt-5 pl-5 p-4">
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group pr-4">
      <legend class="mb-4">Join Today</legend>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
          {{ form.first_name|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
          {{ form.last_name|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
          {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
          {{ form.country|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
          {{ form.city|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
          {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
          {{ form.password1|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
          {{ form.password2|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Checkbox">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="Checkbox">&nbsp;Access Challenge Country</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button style="border-radius: 0; width: 200px; padding-left: 4px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="border-top pt-3">
    <small class="text-muted">
      Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my countries.html

```
{% extends 'shared/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

<div class="content-section p-5 mt-5 pl-4">

<table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-6" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>No: </th>
          <th>Countries: </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

{% for post in posts %}

<table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-6" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
    <tbody>
      {% if user.access_challange %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
          <td><a class="text-uppercase" href="{% url 'users:cities' post.pk %}">{{ post.email }}</a>
        </td>
        {% else %}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
          <td><a class="text-uppercase" href="{% url 'users:cities' post.pk %}">{{ post.country }}</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endif %}
    </tbody>
</table>


{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

</div>
```

If user checks 'access challenge area' checkbox I want to show only his email address and hide his city name and address.

Answer (score 0):

In your template in the condition `{% if user.access_challenge %}` change it to `{% if request.user.access_challenge %}`

Make sure you have the following template context processor in your settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
...
'django.core.context_processors.request',
...)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that without using JavaScript?

Comment: @Almaz In which template do you want the result?

Comment: I changed {% if user.access_challenge %} to {% if request.user.access_challenge %}. But I still can see other information

Comment: @Almaz check if the tags are opened and closed in the correct places. Like I can see your `{% else %}` inside `</tr>` tag. It would be easier to know in which template you are expecting the result as there are two html provided.

Comment: Now I left only {% email %} with no HTML tags. Still not working. :( 

 {% for store in address %}
   {% if user.access_challenge %}
   {{ user.email }}
   {% else %}
<table>

Comment: Have you changed `AUTH_USER_MODEL` as `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'` in your settings.py file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188591/discussion-between-sanip-and-almaz).

Comment: Yes I have AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User set.

Comment: Make sure the user you are logged in with has ticked the checkbox and the if clauses are properly placed in the html.